# Format figure caption when using minipage

Tags: floats, minipage

I am using `minipage` within `figure` environment, and I want to maintain only the figure name, and sort of "sub caption" to the `minipage`.

MWE:

Currently, this is how I plot the figure:

```tex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}
        \caption{a part }
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}
          \caption{b part}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Require figure title format:

[image]

Comment: Will you be need to cross-reference the subfigures?

Comment: Not really. I will only cross-reference the entire figure in my text. Where needed, I will use (a) and (b) to describe the subfigures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need to cross-reference the subfigures individually, you don't need custom `\caption` directives for them.

[image]

Aside: As the `subcaption` package isn't fully compatible with the `IEEEtran` document class, this answer deliberately doesn't make use of the that package.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}
  
  \medskip\footnotesize\centering (a) part 
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}
  
  \medskip\footnotesize\centering (b) part
  \end{minipage}

\caption{Required output format} \label{fig:required}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to Figure \ref{fig:required}.

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

- Use of the `subcaption` package in ˙IEEEtran`documentclass throw warning, that`caption`package (which is loaded by`subcaption` package) will not be used but default document class caption settings.
- However, if instead of it is used older `subfig` package, there is not problems (warning, error) at compilation, since it is compatible with `IEEEtra` document class. So the posible simple solution for your problem can be:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}   it givers warning that instead `caption` is used default caption setup.
\usepackage{subfig}% works without any problem
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[part]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\hfill 
\subfloat[part]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Required output format} 
    \label{fig:required}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to Figure \ref{fig:required}.

\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem with `subcaption` in `IEEEtran` is messing up with my settings. `Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation`

Comment: @arilwan, i got only warning that instead of `caption` will be used default caption setup. However, this warning disappear if instead `subcaption` is used `subfig` package,  Now added to my MWE.